# How to implement a dynamic URL for an image in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
<div class="card-img-little" style="background-image:url("@("~/ImagesAds/" + Model.ImageName)")" asp-append-version="true"></div>
```

Client can't load image from browser.

Comment: _Client can't load image from browser_ Is there an error message? What does `background-image:url("@("~/ImagesAds/" + Model.ImageName)")` resolve to? Check the browser dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Url.Content`,it can converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.:

```
<div class="card-img-little" style="background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/ImagesAds/"+Model.ImageName)')" asp-append-version="true"></div>
```